# mac Terminal app:what is the shortcut for "goto next tab"?

Tags: macos, terminal, shortcut

In terminal app,when I enter "command + {" or "command + {",it will go next  or before window, not next tab,who can tell me ,why?

Comment: Are you sure you are not pressing `cmd + [` ?

Comment: final ,I found ,the answer is "shift + command + }"。 but,in teminal menu,it show the "command + {" is shortcut for "show pervious tab"

Comment: oh,shit ! I am so stupid。 "command + }"  need to entered "shift + command + }",otherwise, it produce "command + ]",not "command +}"

Answer (score 2):

You probably entered <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> accidentally, since they do change the window.

Make sure to enter <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> as they produce <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> respectively.

This is because <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> = <kbd>{</kbd>, etc., depending on your keyboard layout. (Just as you would press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> to type `{`, provided you're using the English or some similar keyboard layout.)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to switch tabs.

You can use `command + shift + }`, `swipe with three fingers`, or use `command + [tab number, i.e. 1]`.

Comment: first,how to use "three fingers" to swith tabs.it need self setting?

Comment: second,command + tab number,   such "command +2", it will switch to second window,not tab

Comment: Sorry, I use TotalTerminal; it hadn't occurred to me that the stock terminal might be different for command + number switching. For three fingers, you'll obviously need a Mac with a trackpad; go to System Preferences -> Trackpad and under Gestures, change the setting for "Swipe between pages" to "Swipe with three fingers".

Comment: Wow, that's awesome!  three fingers is so easy to switch tab

Comment: Haha, yup. Just keep in mind that it will affect other programs too (i.e. internet browsers) -- but honestly I really prefer it that way.

Answer (score 0):

final ,I found ,the answer is "shift + command + }"。 but,in teminal menu,it show the "command + {" is shortcut for "show pervious tab"。

Comment: Well, how do you usually type the *character* `{` or `}`?